# How to assign TextEditingController to dynamicaly created textfield in model and retrieve data from TextEditingController in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, texteditingcontroller

What I actually want is to create text fields against each index of my list and display this list of text fields in expansion tile with Title 'index' of list and `children` are `Textfields` which user will create dynamically on button click so I Created list of text fields dynamically and  now want to assign `TextEditingController` to each of textfields and retirive data

This is my Model I created

```
class MyModel {
  List<Widget> widgets;
  bool isShow = false;
  MyModel({ required this.widgets, required this.isShow});
}
```

This is my Controller

```
class DummyController extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<MyModel> myModelList = [];
  addTextFieldToDay(var index) {
    myModelList[index].widgets.add(TextField());
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And here is how I am calling above function and displaying textfields

```
ListView.builder(
                   itemCount: vm.myModelList.length,
                   itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                     return ExpansionTile(
                         title: Text('Day ${index + 1}'),
                              children: [
                                IconButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      vm.addTextFieldToDay(index);
                                    },
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
                                Container(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    height: 150,
                                    child: ListView(children:vm.myModelList[index].widgets)
                                ),
```

I tried all previously asked question solutions: But the problem i faced in this is i don't know how to get value of specific index controller
i.e

```
List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];

TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
controllers.add(controller);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how achieve this I remove model class and create List of dynamic type and added days to my list with key value pair

```
  class DummyController extends ChangeNotifier {

  List days = [];
  int addedDay =0;
  List finalMap = [];

  addDaysToList(){
    addedDay++;
    days.add({'day$addedDay':<TextEditingController>[]});
    finalMap.add({'day$addedDay':<String>[]});
    notifyListeners();
  }

  addTextFieldsToList(var index){
    days[index]['day${index+1}'].add(TextEditingController());
    notifyListeners();
  }}
```

And this is what i do in my view

```
  Container(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 500,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: vm.days.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        return ExpansionTile(
                          title: Text('Day ${index + 1}'),
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  vm.addTextFieldsToList(index);
                                },
                                icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
                            Container(
                                color: Colors.grey[300],
                                height: 150,
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: vm.days[index['day${index+1}'].length,
                                    itemBuilder: ((context, mindex) {
                                      return TextField(
                                        controller: vm.days[index]['day${index+1}'][mindex],);
                  })) ),],);
```

})),),),

Answer (score 0):

It here:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<Widget> listData = [];

  List<TextEditingController> listDataCTL = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  var ctl = TextEditingController(text: "index");
                  var textF = TextField(
                    controller: ctl,
                  );
                  listData.add(textF);
                  listDataCTL.add(ctl);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Text("Add")),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listData.length + 1,
                itemExtent: 50,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == 0) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print(listDataCTL.first.text);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text('Header'),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return Container(
                    child: listData[index - 1],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```